# SQL and Access calculating a sum value based on a variable field.

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Applogies if you saw my previous post. It was 'closed' for being open ended.

What i have is a three table system for Cars Salesman and Customers.  This is mimicking a very simple Car sales system.

Within the Car Table is the following fields:

Registation:
Make:
Model:
Date of Purchase:
Customer ID:
Salesman ID:
Date Sold:
Date bought:
Price:

or each sale, made by a salesperson, they will earn a commission based on the following table:

```
Car Price(£)        % Commission

0-5000          5
5000-10000          6
10000-15000         7
15000+          8
```

The car is always sold for the price specified in the car details table.

Do I commission rate somewhere within the table (and automatically calculate this)r as a separate table.

If I am going to store this within the Car Table, how would I get the database to automatically calculate the commision and put it in the table, so that when the car is sold ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not open up a new question for the same issue; simply edit your original question, and flag it for re-opening.

Comment: I had no idea that you could do this... My bad. Sorry.

Comment: Your commission table should have two columns, one for the minimum price and one for the maximum price defining the range.

Comment: That wouldn't be such a bad idea actually. And then calculating the commission would then be a sinch. Just use a WHERE Price Between the two values :-) GENIUS!

Comment: @user2111501 dont use the WHERE to find price, join tables using BETWEEN.  use WHERE only to find out if car was or not sold.  see my answer below.  fully functional.

Comment: @KingJohnno how about taking a look at the answer to the question you asked?  you are new here, so learn this: the protocol is that you take a minimal amount of time to examine and comment answers given to questions you pose.  answers take time to compose and prepare and review, the least you owe someone is to examine their answers and give feedback.  welcome, noob!  :)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution, programmatically speaking, would be to create a table COMMISSION with 4 fields: Id_Commission, Nr_Commission_Min_Value,  Nr_Commission_Max_Value,  Nr_Commission_Percent

you would then call a select statement like (tested and working in mysql, whose tsql is very, very similar to msaccess's):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id_Car, Car.Ds_Car_Description, Car.Nr_Car_Price, Commission.Nr_Commission_Percent * Car.Nr_Car_Price / 100 As Commission_Payable FROM Car LEFT JOIN Commission ON (Car.Nr_Car_Price BETWEEN Commission.Nr_Commission_Min_Value AND Commission.Nr_Commission_Max_Value) WHERE Car.Ic_Car_Sold = 1 ORDER BY Car.Nr_Car_Price DESC
```

below, the sql for creating and populating these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Commission (
  Id_Commision int(11) NOT NULL,
  Nr_Commission_Min_Value double NOT NULL,
  Nr_Commission_Max_Value double NOT NULL,
  Nr_Commission_Percent double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO Commission (Id_Commision, Nr_Commission_Min_Value, Nr_Commission_Max_Value, Nr_Commission_Percent) VALUES

(0, 0, 5000, 5),
(1, 5001, 10000, 6),
(2, 10001, 15000, 7),
(3, 15001, 1000000000000, 8);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Car (
  Id_Car int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Ds_Car_Description varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  Nr_Car_Price double NOT NULL,
  Ic_Car_Sold tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (Id_Car)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO Car (Id_Car, Ds_Car_Description, Nr_Car_Price, Ic_Car_Sold) VALUES
(1, 'Lotus', 20000, 1),
(2, 'Renault 5', 1000, 1),
(3, 'Audi A3', 6000, 1),
(4, 'Fiat Mille', 300, 1),
(5, 'Land Rover', 12000, 0),
(6, 'Lotus', 25000, 1);
```

in naming fields, i use Id for main index, Nr for numbers, Ds for strings and Ic for booleans.  a standard i picked up designing dbs for Banco do Brasil.